# How to create a automatic <table> if there is data in the database, php

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a database created in MySql with 8 tables, with products. I want to automatic, it creates an tr and td in a table, as i have more and more data in the database tables.

*I already try to find information about it, but i couldn't understand how it works.

this is what i have so far:

```
<?php
        //Connect to DataBase//
        $link=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','produtos');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        exit("falhou a conexão ao mysql:".mysqli_connect_error());

        //Codification type//
        mysqli_query($link,"set names utf8");

        //Select from DataBase//
        $query="Select * FROM fornos";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if (!$result)
            exit("Erro na query SELECT: " . mysqli_error($link));
        $fornos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $imagem = $fornos['image_link'];
        $preco = $fornos['preco'];
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        //Finish the Conection//
        mysqli_close($link);
?>


<?php
                        echo '<table id="tabela1">';
                    while ($fornos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td class='products_td'> .$preco </td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                        echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td class='products_td'><img class='img_product' src=' echo 'images/fornos/'.$imagem'></td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                        echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td class='products_td'>Informações</td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                        echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td class='products_td_buy'>Comprar</td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                    }
                        echo '</table>';

                    ?>
```

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc($id) ? may be mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and also check quoting in echo statments

Comment: share one table structure and what output you want...

Comment: @RakeshSharma yes, i already changed the `mysqli_fetch_assoc($id)` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` thank you

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a condition to check whether there are entries or not:

```
<?php

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    echo '<table>';

    // YOUR CODE TO PRINT THE TABLE ROWS

    echo '</table>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Yeah, it result, but i try to put another "product" (in the database table) and it just show 1 instead of showing the 2 of them (because i will and more products later )

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Please clarify.

Comment: I have a table in mySQL with products, and i want them to show in my html/php page, inside of a table. But imagine if i had 2 or 3 products in mySQL Table and i want to add another i would like to automaticaly it creates another row in the table. (the site will be to sell procducts)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<?php
......
......
$sytax = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `TABLE`"); // anything you want
echo "<table><tr>";
while($make_this = mysql_fetch_array($sytax)){
?>
   <td><?php echo $make_this['Field_in_your_table']; ?></td>
<?php
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

`<table>`

`<?php`

```
   while ($fornos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($id)){
```

?>

```
       <tr>
              <td class='products_td'><?php echo $preco ?></td>
              // similarly other data

    <?php
        }
       ?>
    </table>
```